# bootstrap.js ie9 compatibility mode hangs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I am expereiencing a bootstrap.js-IE9 issue.
When my page is loaded in IE9 it freezes at glance.
Forcing IE9 into Compability mode with the dev tools solves the problem.
However, It should work without that too.

You can test this at [my mini app](http://smalltracker.cloudfoundry.com/).

The page is rather simple and doesn't have any exotic features yet as you can see in the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welkom bij STT!</title>
<script src="/resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main" class="container">

<div class="row" >
    <div class="span1"><span><img src="" alt="Logo" title="Logo"/></span></div>
    <div id="registration" class="span2 btn disabled ">registreer</div>
    <div id="accounting" class="span2 btn disabled ">accounting</div>
    <div id="reporting" class="span2 btn disabled ">rapportage</div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span3"><span>Welcome Jurgen Goossens</span></div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="span8 well">welkom bij STT!</div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div id="customers" class="span2 btn "><a href="/customer/">klanten</a></div>
        <div id="performance" class="span2 btn "><a href="/tasktype/">taken</a></div>
        <div id="users" class="span2 btn "><a href="/user/">gebruikers</a></div>
        <div class="span5"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea what this is related to ?

Comment: Do actual Bootstrap demo pages like this one cause it to hang too? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/justified-nav.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not bootstrap al all :(.
After a long search I found that following custom CSS code did the trick of freezing IE9 :

```
.btn:first-letter,
label:first-letter,
.navbar-inner .brand:first-letter
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Need to further into that but that's another quest ...

Tnx for the help

Answer (score 2):

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` is the "almost standards" mode. Also, if there is anything above the doctype-declaration, IE automatically goes into quirksmode. Furthermore, [**bootstrap requires the html5 doctype**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html), so you must replace the oldschool HTML 4.01 doctype with

```
<!doctype html>
```

and you should add

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

to the beginning of the `<head>` section (or at least before any script-tags!). See [**IE8, IE9 and IE10 Complications**](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) (middle of page).

Comment: Tnx for your wanser. However, I tried that also and didn't resolve the problem.  However, adapted it to the correct Doctype as I should have done from the start.